# Githubpages hosted Vue app sets text opacity to 1%

Tags: vue.js, github, deployment, github-pages

I want to host my frontend (vue-cli) app on github pages. I ran a npm run build command and pushed the dist folder to its own branch. I set that branch to be hosted by githubpages. Everything seems to work fine, but the text on page is not visible - it is set to 1% opacity. This only happens to text elements that i specified opacity in css for. Why would it be setting opacity of my text elements to 1%?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include your CSS.